# How to extract the current python file name with a module?

Tags: python, operating-system, sys

I am building a module for a simple email task when a file is done running.  It is called emaildone.py:

```
import sys
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
import datetime
global fileName
fileName=os.path.basename(sys.argv[0][:-3])

def whendone(to, fro=None, fname=fileName):
    if fro is None:
        fro = to
    #Email me confirmation of run    
    fname=fileName
    sendTo=to
    sendFrom=fro
    date=str(datetime.date.today())
      
    # Create the root message and fill in the from, to, and subject headers
    msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msgRoot['Subject'] = fname
    msgRoot['From'] = sendFrom
    msgRoot['To'] = sendTo
    msgRoot.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'
    #msgText = MIMEText('no alternative text version')
    #msgAlternative.attach(msgText)
    
    # Encapsulate the plain and HTML versions of the message body in an
    msgText = """
    The """+fname+""" job has ran successfully for """+date+"""
    """
    
    part1 = MIMEText(msgText, 'plain')
    msgRoot.attach(part1)
    
    # Send the email (this example assumes SMTP authentication is required)
    import smtplib
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
    smtp.connect('localhost')
    #smtp.login('exampleuser', 'examplepass')
    smtp.sendmail(sendFrom, sendTo, msgRoot.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
    print('Done!')
```

then in another notebook called test.ipynb I import it like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/my/path/') 
import datetime
import emaildone as email

email.whendone('first.last@email.com')
```

The issue is that fname always comes back as `__main__` instead of the filename.  fname should be "test".  So that the email will have "test" as the subject line and the message will say "The test job has ran successfully for (date)"

How do I get fname to be the current file name vs `__main__`?  When I first started building it sys.argv[0] was working, but somehow it's now showing as `__main__`.

Comment: fname will be filename if you are importing the file, then in that file` __name__` will be file name

Comment: For ex: you have A.py and B.py. And ib B.py there is `print(__name__)`, and in `A.py` you  `import B`, then it will print `B`

Comment: When I set fileName=__name__ I still get the same result

Comment: You create another file `temp.py` and in this import your original file as `import your_file`

Comment: I am doing that I thought.  In my question I state that in another notebook called test.ipynb I import my file, and it runs there, but still produces __main__

Comment: You can use `__file__` in python. it is not available in jupitor notebooks

Comment: I am limited to jupyter notebooks, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues with your code.

1. Your code is getting executed when the module is imported, instead of being executed when called.

Try adding the following to the end of emaildone.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   pass
```

When the interpreter runs a module, the **name** variable is set as  **main** if the module that is being run is the main program.

When `if __name__ == '__main__':` is used, the code in the module is executed only if the file is run directly by calling it and not imported. In your case, when the module is imported, the code is being executed because it does not have the `if __name__ == '__main__'` check.

But if the code imports a module from another module (and does not run the code directly), then the `__name__`  variable is set to that module’s name.

2. You want to get the file name 'test', but you are setting global variable fileName in emaildone.py.

To get 'test', you need to set the variable in test.pynb like so:

```
file_name = os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0]
```

This will give you the file name without the extension. Then you should pass this variable as 'fname' arg to whendone like so:

```
email.whendone('first.last@email.com', fname=file_name)
```

Comment: This actually returns emaildone, which is the file of the module, but I need the file name of the notebook that imports this module.  This is very close though.

Comment: I addressed your issue in my edited response. Did you test it to see if it works?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately __file__ doesn't exist in jupyter notebooks.  From everything I've researched it's just not possible to do what I need.